# SQL запрос: не записывает в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

у меня есть поле, в которое я печатаю символы, буквы, но если напечатать так, то в бд он не записывает. Пример: Jon's.

Вот собственно код

```
<?php
if (isset($title, $meta_d, $meta_k, $date, $description, $text, $author, $cat, $href)) {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE files SET title='$title', meta_d='$meta_d', meta_k='$meta_k', date='$date', description='$description', text='$text', author='$author',cat='$cat',href='$href' WHERE id='$id'");
    if ($result == 'true') {
        echo "<p>Ваш файл успешно обновлен!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Ваш файл не обновлен!</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Вы не заполнили все поля!</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);` Экранирует специальные символы в строке, используемой в SQL-запросе, принмимая во внимание кодировку соединения.
Второй вариант - `$text = htmlspecialchars($text);` - преобразует специальные символы в HTML сущности. Обработайте переменные перед запросом и с *Jon's* проблем не будет

Answer (score 2):

`date='$date',` - date обрамить символами ` - на клавише Ё в латинской раскладке

`text='$text',` - text обрамить символами ` - на клавише Ё в латинской раскладке

все переменные экранировать с помощью `mysql_escape_string()`

И еще,  mysql_query не в виде строки 'true' возвращает результат.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "";
foreach (explode(" ", "title meta_d meta_k date description text author cat href") as $name) {
    if (!isset($$name)) { $sql = ""; break; }
    if ($sql != "") { $sql .= ", "; }
    # Если на сервере отключены ANSI_QUOTES — поменять «\"» на «`» (т.е. "`%s` = %s")
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes
    $sql .= sprintf("\"%s\" = '%s'", $name, mysql_real_escape_string($$name));
}

if ($sql != "") {
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE fields SET %s WHERE id = '%s'", $sql, mysql_real_escape_string($id));
    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    // ...
}
```

По-уму, разумеется, отфакторить это в некую функцию `build_update_statement($table, $where, $updates)`, которой передавать массив-словарь.

А еще более по-уму - выкинуть ext/mysql и использовать PDO. Если есть такая возможность.